# Convert or export Autodesk Revit model to USDZ

Tags: revit, usdz, bim

Does anybody know a way to either

**1)** export a 3D Revit model as a USDZ format (ie via a Plugin)

or

**2)** convert a Revit model (from either RVT, DWG, DGN, FBX, IFC, NWC, DXF, SAT...) to a USDZ format?

I can only find online tools which offer to convert OBJ, STL, DAO, GLB and GTLF to USDZ.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Steve

Comment: You might want to ask that question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. That community is centered around finding program X that can do Y. Here your chances are rather low, as it is mostly centered around writing a program that should do Y and hitting a problem.
Additionally USDZ seems to be a brand new format centered around multimedia. You will probably need to use a wider used intermediate format.

Comment: So I know that the folks at [Point105AR](https://www.point105ar.com) are building a platform to make publishing to USDZ from different tools (FBX mainly) easier. You might want to check them out and see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to convert a Revit model into USDZ yet. Here's the process we usually do when we convert Revit assets into USDZ

1. Export the model to FBX in Revit
2. Artist optimizes the model in Blender/Substance and creates PBR textures, Finally exports the file into .OBJ
3. We convert the OBK along with the PBR textures into a USDZ model